# sameperiodlastyear only works with contiguous date selection

Tags: sql-server, powerpivot, powerbi, dax

I have a data warehouse.  DimDate is connected to FactCost by datekey.  The relationship is many to one and the cross filter direction is single.

I have defined YTD Cost measure:

```
YTD Cost = TOTALYTD(sum(Cost[Amount]),'Date'[DateKey])
```

and then YTD last year

```
LY YTD = CALCULATE([YTD Cost], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Cost[DateKey]))
```

When I try to plot YTD last year I get the following error message:

> MdxScript(Model) (1,53) Calculation error in measure 'Cost'[LY YTD]:
>   Function 'SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR' only works with contiguous date
>   selection.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the problem is that you are passing the date column in your fact table to the `SamePeriodLastYear()` function. I think it would be more standard to pass the key of the date table to the function.

The function returns a table of dates which are then used as a filter (and, of course the filter passes down to the fact table).

```
LY YTD = CALCULATE([YTD Cost], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[DateKey]))
```